# How can I stick a div at the bottom left of the screen

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I've tried many of the solutions related to this topic but I didn't find something which helps my need. I need to position a div as shown in green in the picture.

[image]

The div above the green div has a scrollable table. How can I correctly position the div?

I tried the following but the div is extending to the full page instead of coming within the parent div.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-8">
          <p> Big area </p> 
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-4">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="card col-12">
                    <div class="card-body">
                         <p>Cart Area</p>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card col-12" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; ">
                    <div class="card-body">
                         <p>Green Area</p>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have u tried adding height to your green area?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css on second row that is inside `col-4` to create the boxes go around the page.

```
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 100vh;
justify-content: space-between;
```

But problem is if you don't control the height of first box (col-4) (the one you want to have scroll) by growing page second box will scroll with page.
So after adding css near the `row` you need to give the first column height OR max-height and also `style="overflow:scroll"` to prevent the issue.
I hope this helps.